# Finding the eigenvalues of a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following problem assigned for homework and I was having trouble with it.

Let T : $R^3$ → $R^3$ be the linear transformation that rotates vectors around the z-axis by 180 degrees. List all eigenvalues and describe their corresponding eigenspaces.

Because we are rotating 180 degrees about z, does that mean the only eigenvalue will be -1?

Comment: It does not.  How did you decide that the only eigenvalue should be $-1$?  It would be helpful to see where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: Well I assumed that because we were reflecting about the z axis (going 180 degrees), that would mean we have -1

Comment: Okay, so you're using your understand of $2$-dimensional rotations, which is good.  At some point, you should get a better idea of why $180^\circ$ means an eigenvalue of $-1$, but your idea so far is fine for this problem.  Now, you know what will happen to a vector in the $xy$-plane.  What happens to a vector that points along the $z$-axis?

Comment: Would it be unchanged since it is pointing along the z axis?

Comment: Right.  So what does that tell you about the eigenvalues of the rotation?

Comment: The eigenvalue is just 1?

Comment: $-1$ can't be the **only** eigenvalue, because of what you said earlier.  The point is that **both** $-1$ **and** $1$ are eigenvalues of the rotation.